# How to auto generate E1, E2, E3, E4 in rows in Excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I need Excel to generate the rows like below. How do I do it via a formula?

```
E1
E2
E3
E4
E5
..
..
```

Comment: What have you tried and where is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the letter E and the row #, this is the formula that will do that, but it's unclear from your question.

`="E"&ROW()`